# If NxM multiplication table put in order, what is number on K position?

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search

If I have multiplication table 3x4

```
1 2 3 4
2 4 6 8
3 6 9 12
```

and put all these numbers in the order:

> 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 6 6 8 9 12

What number at the K position?
For example, if K = 5, then this is number 3.

N and M in the range 1 to 500 000. K is always less then N * M.

I've tried to use binary-search like in this([If an NxM multiplication table is put in order, what is number in the middle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28003000/if-an-nxm-multiplication-table-is-put-in-order-what-is-number-in-the-middle)) solution, but there some mistake if desired value not in the middle of sequence.

```
long findK(long n, long m, long k)
{
    long min = 1;
    long max = n * m;
    long ans = 0;
    long prev_sum = 0;
    while (min <= max) {
      ans = (min + max) / 2;
      long sum = 0;
      for (int i = 1; i <= m; i++)
      {
            sum += std::min(ans / i, n);
      }
      if (prev_sum + 1 == sum) break;
      sum--;


      if (sum < k) min = ans - 1;
      else if (sum > k) max = ans + 1;
      else break;
      prev_sum = sum;
   }


      long sum = 0;
      for (int i = 1; i <= m; i++)
      sum += std::min((ans - 1) / i, n);


    if (sum == k) return ans - 1;
    else return ans;
}
```

For example, when N = 1000, M = 1000, K = 876543; expected value is 546970, but returned 546972.

Comment: Wrong ordered numbers in the example. If K = 5, then this is number 3. Expected value is 546970, but returned 546972. What's K?

Comment: @S.M. in ordered sequence counting starts from 1. Added K to example

Comment: The ordered sequence contains less than 3*4 elements.

Comment: Why don´t you store the sorted values as Integers in an ArrayList and just do it like ArrayListName.get(k) ? Or am I not understanding your problem correctly?

Comment: @GitPhilter, calculate and sort values is too slow and required a lot of memory

Comment: `int max = n * m;`, N * M does not fit int, if N and M are in the range 1 to 500 000.

Comment: @S.M. true, but dosen't solve main qustion

Comment: There's an editorial here: https://leetcode.com/articles/kth-smallest-number-in-multiplication-table/ The third method is about binary search.

Comment: @גלעדברקן, this is the solution, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code of third method from this(https://leetcode.com/articles/kth-smallest-number-in-multiplication-table/#) site solve the problem.

```
bool enough(int x, int m, int n, int k) {
int count = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
    count += std::min(x / i, n);
}
return count >= k;
```

}

```
int findK(int m, int n, int k) {
int lo = 1, hi = m * n;
while (lo < hi) {
    int mi = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
    if (!enough(mi, m, n, k)) lo = mi + 1;
    else hi = mi;
}
return lo;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the breakthrough will lie with counting the quantity of factorizations of each integer up to the desired point.  For each integer `prod`, you need to count how many simple factorizations `i*j` there are with `i <= m, j <= n`.  See the [divisor functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function).

You need to iterate `prod` until you reach the desired point, `midpt = N*M / 2`.  Cumulatively subtract `σ0(prod)` from `midpt` until you reach 0.  Note that once `prod` passes `min(i, j)`, you need to start cropping the divisor count, due to running off the edge of the multiplication table.

Is that enough to get you started?

Comment: There's actually a cool binary search application in the third method described here: https://leetcode.com/articles/kth-smallest-number-in-multiplication-table/